# Ansble - adding file contents to the dictionary

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I need to add several dictionaries with file contents to one list for further use with the URI module.
I'm doing it manually now, like this:

```yaml
ansible.builtin.uri:
  method: POST
  body_format: json
  body:
    actions:
      - action: create
          file_path: ".gitlab-ci.yml"
          content: "{{ lookup('file', '.gitlab-ci.yml') }}"
      - action: create
          file_path: "README.md"
          content: "{{ lookup('file', 'README.md') }}"
```

I want to make this task universal so that I don't have to hard specify the name of the files:

```yaml
ansible.builtin.set_fact:
  files:
   - .gitlab-ci.yml
   - README.md

ansible.builtin.uri:
  method: POST
  body_format: json
  body:
    actions: ["
      {% for fs in files -%}
      {
        'action': 'create',
        'file_path': '{{ fs }}',
        'content': '{{ lookup('file', fs) }}'
      }{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
      {%- endfor %}"
      ]
```

The content of the file is thus stored in the actions[*]content variable, but only as a string because the file contains markup. If you replace lookup with the line 'Hello World', the json is generated normally.
Could you please tell me how to use `loop` and `lookup` to save the contents of a file with the `content` key in the `actions` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the filter [*indent*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.indent) to properly indent the [block](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#812-literal-style). Then [*filter*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#id11) the structure by *from_yaml*

```yaml
    actions: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for fs in files %}
      - action: create
        file_path: {{ fs }}
        content: |
          {{ lookup('file', fs)|indent(4) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  actions:
  - action: create
    content: |-
      Content of .gitlab-ci.yml
      line 2
      line 3
      # EOF
    file_path: .gitlab-ci.yml
  - action: create
    content: |-
      Content of README.md
      line 2
      line 3
      # EOF
    file_path: README.md
```

You should be able to use it in the *uri* module

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.uri:
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    body: "{'actions': {{ actions|to_json }} }"
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that really helped.
I now know about the filter in jinja2 - thanks.